# Google chrome extensions launch event

Tags: events, background, google-chrome-extension, launch

I'm working with my first chrome extension, so I do not know how to run specific script with browser launch event. For my case I need to load background page, but it has http protocol, so as I read [here](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/chrome/apps/docs/background.html#example-window_open) I can load it using window.open but I need to load only once, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your background page will start executing when the browser is opened (and *only* when the browser opens). So if you need to do something then, you can just write it directly in the code in your `background.html`.

Comment: The problem is to embed (host, frame) some page with audioplayer and in my popup I want to control it. I tied to load background_page from manifest with my external URL but I have: Could not load extension from '/Users/lufton/Documents/blahblah/'. Unable to load background page "http://mysite.com". I want to make kind of radio or something simular using public audio library.

Comment: This is not correct.  I create a notification in the background.js.  Everytime the browser is started OR the default_popup is launched, the notification is created again.